# Extracting a paragraph between two key words in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm a beginner in Perl, and am trying to print a paragraph between two key words after searching for a key word.

So this should search for `ooaijp01.intlb.net-pool` and if it matches it should print a paragraph between a key word

Below is the input file. Could you please help me to achieve this.
and it should ignore the case sensitivity

and the file name would be gslb_data

```
pool {
   name           "ooaijp01.intlb.net-pool"
   ttl            *
   preferred      ***
   alternatkke      **
   fallback       *****
   fallback_ipv4  ****
   partition "Common"

   member         *****
   member         *******
}

pool


pool {
   name           "ooaijj01.intlb.net-pool"
   ttl            *
   preferred      ***
   alternatkke      **
   fallback       *****
   fallback_ipv4  ****
   partition "Common"

   member         *****
   member         *******
}

pool


pool {
   name           "ooaijk01.intlb.net-pool"
   ttl            *
   preferred      ***
   alternatkke      **
   fallback       *****
   fallback_ipv4  ****
   partition "Common"

   member         *****
   member         *******
}

pool
```

I have tried with this code but it's not working.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open my $fh, '<', 'file_to_check'
    or die "Cannot open: $!";    # file_to_check is my file name
my @file = <$fh>;
close $fh;

for (0 .. $#file) {

  if ($file[$_] =~ /"ooaijp01.intlb.net-pool"/) { # is my key word ooaijp01.intlb.net-pool

    my $start = $_;

    while ($start >= 0 && $file[$start] !~ /pool/) {
      $start--;
    }

    my $end = $_;

    while ($end <= $#file && $file[$end] !~ /pool/) {
      $end++;
    }

    print "\n@file[$start+1..$end-1]";
  }
}
```

my expected output should be

```
pool {
   name           "ooaijp01.intlb.net-pool"
   ttl            *
   preferred      ***
   alternatkke      **
   fallback       *****
   fallback_ipv4  ****
   partition "Common"

   member         *****
   member         *******
}

pool
```

and i wanted to save in a separate output file

Comment: You can slurp the whole document into a variable and then try to get the value between the pattern . This should help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has no one mentioned the 'range operator' yet?

Something like this:

```
print "pool {\n";
while ( <DATA> ) {
    print if /ooaijp01.intlb.net-pool/ .. /\}/;
}
```

Will print any lines between the start and end patterns.

Answer (score 0):

@clement: You can try below perl code :

**Without Slurping:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = $ARGV[0];
my ($file,$ext)=$filename =~ /(.*?)(\..*?)/;
my $outfile = "$file" . "\.out";
open my $fh,'<',$filename or die "File $filename cannot be opened: $!";
open my $oh,'>',$outfile or die "File $outfile cannot be opened : $!";
my $start=0;
while(<$fh>)
{
     if($_ =~ /ooaijp01\.intlb\.net\-pool/is)
      { 
         $start = $.;
     print $_ . "\n";
      }

     elsif($start>0 && $_ !~ /pool/)
      {
          print $_ . "\n";
        }

}
```

**Using Slurping :**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = $ARGV[0];
my ($file,$ext)=$filename =~ /(.*?)(\..*?)/;
my $outfile = "$file" . "\.out";
open my $fh,'<',$filename or die "File $filename cannot be opened: $!";
open my $oh,'>',$outfile or die "File $outfile cannot be opened : $!";

my $document = do {
         local $/ = undef;
         open my $fh,'<',$filename or die "Couldn't open the file $filename:$!";
       <$fh>;
      };


sub Processing
{
    my $result = $_[0];
     if($result =~ /ooaijp01\.intlb\.net\-pool/isg)
       {
          print $oh $result . "\n";
        }
     }          

$document =~ s/(pool\s*\{.*?\s*\}\s*pool)/Processing($1)/eisg;    #Between the keywords pool
```

Comment: The question was not clear and as per his code , i have modified . Can i know why my answer was given negative ?

Comment: Edit the question and post your expected output for the input that you have given.

Comment: Hi Praveen... i have editing my question.. Are you able to have a look... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;

my $toprint;
my @out;
while(<DATA>) {
   chomp;
   if (/^\s*pool\b/) { # ^\s* is mandatory to not catch net-pool
      if ($toprint) {
         say $_ for @out;
      }
      $toprint = 0;
      @out = ($_);
   } elsif ($_ =~ /\booaijp01\.intlb\.net-pool\b/) {
      $toprint = 1;
      push @out, $_;
   } else {
      push @out, $_;
   }
}

if ($toprint) {
   say $_ for @out;
}

__DATA__
pool {
   name           "ooaijp01.intlb.net-pool"
   ttl            *
   preferred      ***
   member         *******
}

pool {
   name           "ooaijp01.intlb.net-pool"
   ttl            *
   preferred      ***
   member         *******
}

pool {
   name           "ooaijp01.xxxx"
   ttl            *
   preferred      ***
   member         *******
}

pool {
   name           "ooaijp01.intlb.net-pool"
   ttl            *
   preferred      *
   member         *
}
```

**Output:**

```
pool {
   name           "ooaijp01.intlb.net-pool"
   ttl            *
   preferred      ***
   member         *******
}

pool {
   name           "ooaijp01.intlb.net-pool"
   ttl            *
   preferred      ***
   member         *******
}

pool {
   name           "ooaijp01.intlb.net-pool"
   ttl            *
   preferred      *
   member         *
}
```